# Kineticjs - bind draggable image to canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

I'm using Kinetcjs library for handling images in our canvas so we can drag images about within the Canvas.

One issue I'm running into is that users can drag images loaded into the canvas off the canvas. This obviously causes problems when we try to get the image when the user has finished with the image as they can upload an image halfway down the canvas.

Is there anyway we can bind it so that the top of the image cant be dragged past the top of the canvas and the bottom of the image dragged past the bottom of the canvas?

Comment: well, you have to show some code, because generally the images you create in kineticJS are limited to being inside the created canvas.

Comment: It is possible that you have the image outside of the canvas and have not bound it to the canvas in the first place.

Comment: If you have not bound it completely to the canvas, then you can use jQuery draggable to achieve what you are asking for. If you have bound it, then there is a dragBoundFunc in KineticJS which will let you limit the movement of objects in the canvas

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working. For anyone interested in how to do this I did it like so:

```
photo.setDragBoundFunc(function(pos){                           
    var yBound = stage.getHeight()-newPhotoHeight;

    if(pos.y >= yBound && pos.y < 0)  {
        var newY =  pos.y;
    } else if(pos.y < yBound) {
        var newY = yBound;
    } else if(pos.y > 0) {
        var newY = 0;
    } else {
        var newY = pos.y;
    }

    return {
            x: this.getAbsolutePosition().x,
            y: newY
           }
    });
```